# How do I modify a css property onClick using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the opacity and pointer-events of two elements when i click another element, i searched and i was able to change the opacity using a const for the style and setState (which i dont really understand fully yet) but its a hard no on the pointer-events. I ended up writing in JQuery so you understand better what i want to do.

```
const App = () => {

  const iluminar = () => {
    $('#oscurecido').css("opacity", 0);
    $('#oscurecido').css("pointer-events", "none");
    $('#sesion').css("opacity", 0);
    $('#sesion').css("pointer-events", "none");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="oscurecido" onClick={iluminar}></div>
      <Router>
        <Nav/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Productos}/>
          <Route path="/Carrito" exact component={Carrito}/>
          <Route path="/" component={Err}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      {true ? <Sesion/> : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't combine between jQuery and react. This is really a bad practice.

Comment: Check out CLSX: https://github.com/lukeed/clsx#readme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is create a class with all the css code you want to apply to it onClick. Then you create a state with default value to false and onClick you ser it to true. Assign that class if the state is true.

```
.some-class { ...css properties }


const App = () => {
const [ iluminated, setIluminated ] = useState(false)

return (
<div className="App">
  <div id={iluminated ? 'some-class' : ''} onClick={() => setIluminated(true)}></div>
  <Router>
    <Nav/>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Productos}/>
      <Route path="/Carrito" exact component={Carrito}/>
      <Route path="/" component={Err}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  {true ? <Sesion/> : null}
</div>
```

)
}

Comment: If that was helpful I would apreciate if you mark the answer as correct.